# Proof that $a^n-n$ diverges if $1<a$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If we know that $a^n$ grows unbounded for $1<a$ and that $a^n\to 0$ if $a<1$, I am trying to prove that $\{a^n-n\}$ is not Cauchy if $1<a$.

Intuitively we should be able to show that for large enough $m<n$ we have

$$ |m-a^m-(n-a^n)|=|m-n+a^n-a^m|\ge 1$$

Of course we can choose $n$ large enough that $m<a^n$.  Not sure how much this helps.

I tried using the reverse triangle inequality but that didn't seem to help.

I could factor out

$$ \left(\frac 1 {a^n}\right)\left|\frac{m}{a^n}-\frac{n}{a^n}+1-a^{m-n}\right|$$

But I don't see how to see any way to use this.  And I can't really think of anything else to do to this.  I know that if we had the full power of calculus we could use L'Hospital's Rule, but this is too basic to permit using derivatives.  We would also need to know the derivative of exponential functions, and the proof of that I recall uses knowledge of the FTC, so I don't think any line of thinking in this direction could be helpful.

Comment: You have $a_{n + 1} - a_n = a^n(a - 1) - 1$, with $a > 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}a^n-n>\frac{a^n}2&\iff\frac{a^n}2>n\\&\iff\frac{a^n}n>2,\end{align}which is true if $n$ is large enough, since $a>1$, and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n}n=\infty$. So, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n}2=\infty$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a^n-n)=\infty$.

---

Here's another possibility. Suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a^n-n=l$, for some real number $l$. Then$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{a^{2n}}2-n\right)=\frac12\lim_{n\to\infty}(a^{2n}-2n)=\frac l2,$$and therefore$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left((a^n-n)-\left(\frac{a^{2n}}2-n\right)\right)=\frac l2;$$in other words,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(a^n-\frac{a^{2n}}2\right)=\frac l2.$$But, in fact,\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(a^n-\frac{a^{2n}}2\right)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}a^n\left(1-\frac{a^n}2\right)\\&=\infty\times(-\infty)\\&=-\infty.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Maybe first try showing the $a^n > 2n$ for sufficiently large $n.$   This is quite easy to do by induction.

Comment: The sequence $\sqrt{2n + 1} - \sqrt{n}$ is Cauchy, even though $\sqrt{2n + 1} > \sqrt{n}$.

Comment: What is wrong with this approch? Why does it get downvotes? If $a^n>2n$ then $a^n-n>n$ so $a^n-n$ is unbounded and hence can't be Cauchy.

Comment: To avoid giving an Answer that is much shorter than the Question you responded to, you might go into the details of the "quite easy ... induction."